# Can´t send mail using Java Mail in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jakarta-mail

It works in the Windows machine but throws: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: wo35.wiroos.host, 25; timeout -1;  When trying to send an email in Ubuntu.

I am using Tomcat both in Windows and in the ubuntu server.

I am using javax.mail version 1.5.5

Code that is not working:

```
String host = "wo35.wiroos.host";

 public void sendEmail(String emailBody, String to) throws AddressException, MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
//Get the session object  
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
            }
        });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user, "From"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Subject");
        message.setText(emailBody);

        //send the message  
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Ok");
}
```

Comment: "Couldn't connect" means either the host is down, **or** it is not running an SMTP service on the standard port, **or** something is blocking the connection; e.g. a firewall or a network config issue.

Comment: The problem is most likely NOT the code.

Comment: I am also using ngix as a proxy with tomcat

Comment: You are trying to talk to an SMTP server.  Nginx should not relevant unless you are trying to use it as a mail proxy as per: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/.  Ditto Tomcat.  You haven't said what "host" is ...

Comment: Just added the host

Comment: I can get a connection to that host on port 25.  So it is either a networking or firewalling issue.  (There could be a block on your server on all outgoing SMTP connections, for example.  Or for SMTP connections from the nginx or tomcat user.  Selinux, Apparmor or other "hardening" can do this kind of thing to protect you from becoming an inadvertent spammer if your web server is compromised. )

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug), as well as lots of other tips for problems you're likely to run in to such as how to connect through a proxy server.

Comment: *TL;DR: Send mail to `localhost`, not a remote server.* Once you get your code working, you may still experience that the mail server is unavailable, e.g. down for maintenance, which will make `Transport.send(message)` throw an exception. You don't want that. Instead, you'd want the email to be queued locally, and sent when mail server is available. To do that, start a local SMTP service (all Linux distributions have at least one, e.g. sendmail, postfix, exim, ...), configure it to allow relay from `localhost`, then configure Java program to use `localhost` as the mail host.